# Join all the sublists together and grab the first one

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects

I want to be able to pull the last invoice containing a product in a category
Category->Product->Invoice

```
(from p as Product in cat
 where p.InvoiceList.Where(function(o) o.InvoiceDate >= MAX_ONE)
 select p.InvoiceList.Where(function(o) o.InvoiceDate >= MAX_ONE)
).FirstOrDefault()
```

I just can't seem to wrap my head about how to get this done.

EDIT: a sample SQL statement that would accomplish my goal.  If only I could translate it...

```
SELECT    TOP 1 i.InvoiceID, i.InvoiceDate, i.TotalAmount
FROM         Category as c INNER JOIN
                  Product as p ON p.categoryID = c.categoryID INNER JOIN
                  InvoiceProducts as ip ON ip.productID = p.productID INNER JOIN
                  Invoice as i ON ip.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID 
WHERE     c.categoryID = 3
ORDER BY InvoiceDate DESC
```

Comment: Linq offers a [`.LastOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault.aspx) method.  Might be easier.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly do you need? Last invoice for each category? A single last invoice from all categories? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat.SelectMany(p => p.InvoiceList).OrderBy(o => o.InvoiceDate).LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: Awesome this is what I needed.  The key was "SelectMany" it got me where I needed to go.

Comment: Curiosity what would this look like in query syntax?

Comment: @Steve: it looks like 'from p in cat
from o in p.InvoiceList' because `SelectMany` does not have in query syntax

Comment: with some added fitlers this is the result.
cat.ProductList.SelectMany(function(o) o.InvoiceList).Where(function(o) o.IsVoid = False).OrderByDescending(Function(o)o.InvoiceDate).Select(function(o) o.TotalAmount).FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastInvoice = (from i in context.Invoices
    .where i.Product.CategoryId == categoryId
    .select i)
        .OrderByDescending(i=>i.IbvoiceDate)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What is `context`?  Is that a repository object?

Comment: Yes, the context from where the entities come from, i.e.: EntitiesContainer

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what the OP is doing. :)

Comment: Problem here Alex is I do not have direct access to the Invoice Table, I was forced to access it through the other objects.  I am not using LINQ to Entities but instead just LINQ to Objects.

Comment: Do you have the category object?

Comment: Yes, following @cuong-le sample I was able to do a selectmany and accomplish what I was after.